# SocialEngine installation error 500 (Step 3)

Tags: apache, mysql, http-code-500, socialengine

I'm trying to install SocialEngine (clean install, empty database, legal license key) but I ran into this error message 500 at Step 3 of the installation:

Step 3: Setting up MySQL Database

> MySQLi statement execute error : Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

I found a troubleshooting article about a [Bug in MySQLi Extension Causes Apache 500 Error](http://www.socialengine.net/blog/article?id=161&article=Bug-in-MySQLi-Extension-Causes-Apache-500-Error).

I have uploaded the fixed file and try to install again but it still doesn't work. It terminates at Step 3 again with the same error message.

Comment: Since you paid for a commercial license, why not ask the vendor for support? There's a link in the support section where clients can open a support ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your initial support is expired and you want to try debugging the issue yourself, I would first check the web server's error logs. This is the first place you should look whenever you encounter a 500 - Internal server error. If you're using Apache, this is typically located in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` (though for vhosts a separate location is likely to be set, so check your conf files). It may also be worthwhile to check the system error logs (`/var/log/messages` in linux).

This will give a little more information to help you locate the problem. If you need more detailed info, then a stack trace may help. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.hokstad.com/5-simple-ways-to-troubleshoot-using-strace.html) on how to use [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) with PHP.

If you want more detailed help, you'll need to post the error that's being logged, the stack trace results, and the relevant source code (the section of code mentioned in the patch). Though StackOverflow would probably be more appropriate for this.